# android - delete a row in sql and item in listview

Tags: android

I am trying to delete a row from my db.
I'm using this method:

`public void deletePlayerbyID(int id){mDb.delete(SQLITE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID +"="+id, null);
        }`

called in activity :

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {
              return onLongListItemClick(v,pos,id);
      }
      protected boolean onLongListItemClick(View v, final int pos, long id) {

              AlertDialog.Builder builder = new  AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity.this);
                  builder.setMessage("Are you sure to delete?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {bdHelper.open();
                                 dbHelper.deletePlayerbyID(pos);
                                 Log.i("ListView", "onLongListItemClick id=" + pos);
                                 displayListView();
                             }
                         })
```

Why I cannot delete the selected row from listView ? I have a method that delete all db and it work.

Comment: after deletion call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter to refresh listview

Answer (score 0):

After deleting an element from the data source that the `listView` adapter is using, call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and the view will refresh to reflect the deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following statement you would able to solve the problem

```
db.delete("Table","TITLE=?",new String[]{title});
```

after that

```
adapter = new EntryAdapter(this, items);
         listview.setAdapter(adapter);
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use   notifyDataSetChanged() after delete

```
protected boolean onLongListItemClick(View v, final int pos, long id) {

              AlertDialog.Builder builder = new  AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity.this);
                  builder.setMessage("Are you sure to delete?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {bdHelper.open();
                                 dbHelper.deletePlayerbyID(pos);
                                 Log.i("ListView", "onLongListItemClick id=" + pos);
  notifyDataSetChanged();
                                 displayListView();
                             }
                         })
```

Comment: isn't this kind of problem, because with another method (delete by "name" and not "id") works.I had follow this tut http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html